# Removing ListBoxItems from a bounded ListBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a ListBox that has items that can be dragged and dropped onto a StackPanel. When these items are dropped, I need them to be removed from the ListBox, which is bound to a list.

The item that is beign dropped, and should be removed as an example would be a Person.

```
public class Person()
{
    private int Age {get;set;}
    private string Name {get;set;}

    public Person(){...}

    /*Getter and Setter Methods to follow*/
}
```

**Note** This class is completely arbitrary, and just used as an example.

This class will be bound to a ListBox using the following code. The call to get the list of Person objects, is also not implementation specific.

```
List<Person> personList = PersonDAO.getAll();
listBox.ItemsSource = personList;
listBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

Everything works fine in my application so far, except for removing items from the list.

When an item is dropped, it needs to be removed from the list. How is the proper way to remove the dragged item from the ListBox without removing it from the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think in terms of removing items from a `ListBox`.  Think in terms of removing items from the collection that the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` is bound to.  This lets you avoid writing all kinds of ugly, unwieldy code.

It sounds like you're reluctant to modify the underlying collection of `Person` objects.  OK.  So create a new one, one that's not "all the `Person` objects" but rather "all the `Person` objects still present in the `ListBox`."

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ObservableCollection<Person>` or another collection implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` as here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx

Comment: I may have worded my question wrong. Would the solution above allow me to only remove the item from the ListBox, with no knowledge of the source that is binding to the ListBox?

Comment: I don't think removing *only* from the view being the correct way of working in MVVM

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to filter the person list, like so:

```
List<Person> personList = PersonDAO.getAll();
listBox.ItemsSource = personList;
listBox.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
personListView = (CollectionView)
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(personList);
personListView.Filter += (item) => { someCriteriaForInclusion };
```

When a drag occurs call personListView.Refresh() to reapply the filter.